# Selecting specific rows based on data from other table

Tags: mysql, date, select, join, sqlfiddle

I have the flowing tables:

*See fiddle:* http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c2f/1

I'm struggling to find a way to

> select software.name, systems.pc(or software.pc), systems.user

only for the rows were the software.date field matches the systems.time field
meaning that fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT software.name, software.pc, systems.pc, systems.user
FROM software
JOIN systems
ON software.date = systems.time AND software.pc = systems.pc;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c2f/34/0

Comment: thank you, but this gives output of 4 rows.If the query is correct there should be 2 rows

Comment: @Axxess please provide expected output (add it to your questions by using the [edit] link).

Comment: @Axxess I have updated my answer above, you may try the modified query which will give you 2 rows.

Comment: Yes, it works as it should you and @Parkash Kumar helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use aliases when querying complex data with JOINs, see following:

```
SELECT so.name, sy.pc, sy.user FROM software so 
JOIN systems sy
WHERE so.date = sy.time AND so.pc = sy.pc;
```

Specially, when you have same named columns. As in your case both tables have same column (PC).

Comment: @Axxess Try querying users with the result and also compare pc's of two tables. Then you can figure out the difference.

Comment: @Axxess Also, the result is confusing because of the repeated software names.

Comment: I have found the answer. Thank you for your help :)